# Why is brew doctor stalling on mdfind?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

## The problem

I've been having issues with homebrew, so I thought I'd run `brew doctor`, but it's just stalling on mdfind. `brew --config` also hangs on mdfind after outputting the following:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.4
ORIGIN: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew
HEAD: c2cc58163b54a9ea2ee56febfc722396079c5b9a
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: quad-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.8.3-x86_64
Xcode: 4.6.2
CLT: 4.6.0.0.1.1365549073
LLVM-GCC: build 2336
Clang: 4.2 build 425
```

`brew update` seems to work:

```
$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
```

I can even install things:

```
$ brew install rsnapshot
==> Downloading http://rsnapshot.org/downloads/rsnapshot-1.3.1.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/rsnapshot/1.3.1 --mandir=/usr/local/C
==> make install
  /usr/local/Cellar/rsnapshot/1.3.1: 12 files, 356K, built in 4 seconds
```

And they even work:

```
$ rsnapshot
rsnapshot 1.3.1
Usage: rsnapshot [-vtxqVD] [-c cfgfile] [command] [args]
Type "rsnapshot help" or "man rsnapshot" for more information.
```

## What I've tried

- uninstalling all packages
- untapping all kegs
- reinstalling homebrew
- reinstalling XCode + command line tools
- Installing XQuartz (which I had to do via command line)
- re-indexing my system drive with Spotlight
- resetting the xcode-select path
- deleting `/usr/share/xcode-select/`

## Workaround

After running `brew doctor`, if I terminate the mdfind process twice (one instance spawns after the other is terminated), I finally get a successful return:

```
$ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.
```

Same deal with config:

```
$ brew --config
OMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.4
ORIGIN: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew
HEAD: c2cc58163b54a9ea2ee56febfc722396079c5b9a
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: quad-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.8.3-x86_64
Xcode: 4.6.2
CLT: 4.6.0.0.1.1365549073
LLVM-GCC: build 2336
Clang: 4.2 build 425
X11: 2.7.4 => /opt/X11
System Ruby: 1.8.7-358
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
```

Note how the next item in the config, after the usual stall point, is X11.

## More info

I recently had to remove a manually compiled version of ICU from my system, and there's a small chance that I actually removed a couple of binaries that weren't installed by ICU. I'm not sure, but I thought I'd mention it just in case. Even if makes me sound very silly indeed.

`brew doctor` gives no output on termination.

`brew doctor` seems to stall on the `check_for_latest_xquartz` check in particular, which I've checked with:

```
$ brew doctor check_for_latest_xquartz
```

My `xcode-select` path seems correct:

```
$ xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

`mdfind` *can* find XQuartz:

```
$ mdfind "kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier == 'org.macosforge.xquartz.X11'"
/Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app
```

...but it still doesn't return.

## Related links

- [brew doctor and brew upgrade stopped working](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/18045)
- [brew doctor hangs at mdfind](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/16964) — similar/same issue. User doesn't say what was done to fix it.
- [brew doctor not terminating](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/17426)
- [Unable to run brew --config, doctor, audit.](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/10055)

Comment: Your workaround works for me. Thanks! I'm not totally stuck anymore.

Comment: I am running 10.8.4, and I ran into this problem last night. Thankfully, a reboot was all that is needed to resolve the problem with `brew doctor` and `brew upgrade gtk+` (both got stuck before getting a reboot)

Comment: I'm no longer experiencing this issue (new Mac), but I'll leave this here in case someone provides a solution, or if my attempted solutions are useful.

Answer (score -1):

The last post in your GitHub link seems to answer the question:

> This is by far the most useful thread on this very frustrating topic. I tried everything above and found that brew doctor hung on:
>
> ```
> check_for_autoconf (kill mdfind 2x)
> check_for_latest_xquartz (kill mdfind 2x)
> check_for_linked_keg_only_brews (kill mdfind 4x)
> check_for_osx_gcc_installer (kill mdfind 2x)
> check_for_stray_developer_directory (kill mdfind 2x)
> check_missing_deps (kill mdfind 2x)
> check_standard_compilers (kill mdfind 1x)
> Note that killing mdfind multiple times at least allows brew doctor to continue but that is not a solution.
> ```
>
> When brew doctor finally completed, I noticed one warning:
>
> ```
> check_user_path_2
> Warning: Homebrew's bin was not found in your PATH.
> Consider setting the PATH for example like so
>     echo export PATH='/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
> ```
>
> This added export `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to `~/.bash_profile`.
>   This was also at the beginning of `~/.bash_profile` and twice at the end so I deleted all but the last statement. Opening a new terminal window, now `/usr/local/bin` is at the beginning of my path instead of in the middle.
>
> Now brew doctor runs without hanging!

If this doesn't fix the problem, I suggest contributing to this thread on GitHub or opening a new issue on GitHub, as it may be a bug in homebrew.